# What collected editions does Dust (Sooraya Qadir) make a significant appearence in, prior to/including Utopia?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, suggested-order

My wife has taken a shine to Dust (Sooraya Qadir a member of the x-men), and has said she'd like to get into comics by reading about her.

I'm trying to find all the collected editions she appears in, to get for my wife but I'm having difficulty tracking them down.

I've found this list:

#### Trade Paperback Listing

- New X-Men: X-Posed
- New X-Men: Hellions
- X-Men: The 198 (in Mutant Database)
- New X-Men: Childhood's End
- New X-Men: Childhood's End 2
- New X-Men: Childhood's End 3 - Nimrod
- New X-Men: Childhood's End 4 - Mercury Falling
- New X-Men: Childhood's End 5 - Quest for Magik
- World War Hulk: X-Men
- X-Men: Blinded by the Light
- Astonishing X-Men: Unstoppable
- X-Men: Messiah CompleX
- X-Men: Divided We Stand (flashback)
- Young X-Men: Final Genesis
- X-Men: Secret Invasion
- Young X-Men: Books of Revelations
- Avengers*X-Men: Utopia

I can't figure out which of these show enough of the character to hold my wife's attention (which is currently centred around Dust, not Marvel or even the X-Men).

In which of the above TPBs is Dust a significant character?

For the purposes of this, lets say significant means that she appears on at least three pages in at least two different scenes.

Comment: *Quest for Magik* is my very favorite comic arc but Sooraya is more of a supporting character at that point. What's your threshold for "significant appearance?" For example, in *Magik* she has a couple 2-character scenes but is not the focus of the plot.

Comment: @dunraven "she appears on at least three pages in at least two different scenes."

Comment: yup sorry my bad. I'll work on this when I get a sec to dig into my old New X-Men! But it might be a lot of reading Sooraya in the background for a few choice moments (I had the same experience with Anole, who has a similar standing in the line-up)

Comment: Someone (maybe you?) needs to start a CW answer for this one. I was about to try answering, but the sheer size of that list daunts me more even than 500 rep motivates me!

Comment: Yes, I'm still hoping to tackle this when I'm home and have access to my comics, but the 3-page/2-scene stipulation feels a bit arbitrary and a little daunting. To clarify - is that the rule issue to issue, or in each trade compilation listed? As an introduction to comics, hopping from issue to issue might put your wife off of the comics as Dust is rarely central to the A plot and so the whole endeavor may end up more confusing than inviting.

Comment: @dunraven it's for each TPB listed. You have valid concerns about hoping issue to issue might be off putting. What would you suggest? Feel free to join me in [chat].

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read all of these story arcs, but as far as I can tell Dust only features as a somewhat prominent character in the "Messiah Complex" and "Young X-Men" stories. The rest of the time, she's usually treated as a minor or background character that only appears in a single scene or perhaps has 1-2 lines of dialogue.